# Active Record STI Confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

STI is not working as I think it should under certain conditions.

The models (simplified):

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, class_name: 'OrderItem', inverse_of: :order
end

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :items
  has_one :spec, inverse_of: :order_item
end

class Spec < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order_item, inverse_of: :spec
end

class FooSpec < Spec
end

class BarSpec < Spec
end
```

Schema (simplified):

```
create_table "specs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "type", null: false
  t.bigint "order_item_id", null: false
  ...
end
```

I'm using `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` to avoid n+1 problems in my GraphQL server. I've started getting some STI errors.

From a console, this works fine and returns a `FooSpec` or `BarSpec`:

```
Order.includes(items: :spec).first.items.first.spec
```

Same with this:

```
Order.includes(:items).first.items.includes(:spec).first.spec
```

And this too:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
  .preload(Order.all, :items).first.owners.first.items.first.spec
```

However, this:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(Order.all, items: :spec)
```

And this:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
  .preload(Order.all.map{|o| o.items}.flatten, :spec)
```

Raise an error:

> ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism
>   failed to locate the subclass: 'FooSpec'. This error is raised
>   because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of
>   inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be
>   used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite
>   Spec.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.

Sometimes I'm getting a slightly different error from the app but I cannot reproduce it in the console:

> ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound (Invalid single-table inheritance type:
>   FooSpec is not a subclass of Spec)

Hmm...as you can see, `FooSpec` is most definitely a subclass of `Spec`. These errors usually mean you used `type` as an attribute and did not tell ActiveRecord it's not an STI discriminator. That's not the case here. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. I had this:

```
class FooSpec < Spec
  validates :my_field, inclusion: {in: MyClass::CHOICES}
end
```

When I changed it to this, the problem disappeared:

```
class FooSpec < Spec
  validates :my_field, inclusion: {in: -> (_instance) {MyClass::CHOICES}}
end
```

I do not understand why. `MyClass::CHOICES` is a simple constant holding an array. The class is a [`classy_enum`](https://github.com/AgilionApps/classy_enum).

```
class MyClass < MyClassyEnum
  CHOICES = %w[
    choiceOne
    choiceTwo
  ].freeze
  ...
end
```